# Crack on inside of window on white plastic part

Tags: repair, windows, crack

[image]I noticed a crack on the white plastic part of my window towards the bottom. These are impact windows and were just installed in 2019. I want to see if this was cause for concern? Does this need repair? I attached a photo. What would cause a crack like this?
[image]

Comment: 2019 might still be under warranty.  On the inside it might more cosmetic(ulgy) than structural or needing repair for a function of the window.  Does that white circle do anything?

Comment: The previous owner had them installed. So not sure if that warranty transfers. I moved in last year. The window does not open. It looks cosmetic to me to be honest . I have no clue what the white circle does though.

Comment: The white circle looks  to me like a fastener (nail?)  that the window frame has broken away from (note the circle just above it that it appears to have slid away from, and that it coincides with the break).  Id's say it was just driven sloppily. If the window's still securely held by other fasteners/adhesive, I'd put this in the "pretend I didn't see it" category.

Comment: Lol thank you. I think I’m going to go with this! If it’s just cosmetic it can wait.